# How to filter in postgresSQL and nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to search user that not in the team yet to invite them but right now my function is searching user that in the team only. So now how can I implement the function to search user that not in the team yet.

Here is my following code:

```
exports.searchUserToInvite = async (req, res) => {
  // Grab query
  const query = req.params.q;
  const publicTeamId = req.params.id;
  const teamId = await getTeamId(publicTeamId);
  // Get team data based on id

  // Search for users
  const usersFound = await models.User.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          fullname: {
            [Op.iLike]: "%" + query + "%",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    attributes: [
      "fullname",
      "public_user_id",
      "institution",
      "location",
      "webpage",
      "linkedin",
      "major",
      "picture",
      "verifiedDT",
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Rating,
        attributes: ["skillset_rating", "team_member_rating"],
      },
      {
        model: models.Skill,
        attributes: ["skill"],
      },
      {
        model: models.Team,
        attributes: ["status"],
        where: {
          id: teamId,
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  // Run searches
  const searchData = await Promise.all([usersFound]);
  // Return results
  res.status(200).json(searchData);
};
```

Update add following code model User:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      fullname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      passwordhash: DataTypes.STRING,
      institution: DataTypes.STRING,
      bio: DataTypes.STRING,
      creator_user_id: DataTypes.UUID,
      public_user_id: DataTypes.STRING,
      picture: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
      service: DataTypes.STRING,
      gender: DataTypes.STRING,
      age: DataTypes.INTEGER ,
      altId: DataTypes.STRING,
      location: DataTypes.STRING,
      mergedTo: DataTypes.UUID,
      document: DataTypes.STRING,
      webpage: DataTypes.STRING,
      linkedin: DataTypes.STRING,
      signupIP: DataTypes.STRING,
      major: DataTypes.STRING,
      verifiedDT: DataTypes.DATE,
      couponsUsed: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      teamCredits: DataTypes.INTEGER ,
      resetToken: DataTypes.STRING,
      resetTokenExpires: DataTypes.DATE,
      uniqueToken: DataTypes.STRING,
      expireToken: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    {
      tableName: "Users",
      timestamps: true,
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: false,
          fields: ["email", "id", "fullname", "public_user_id"],
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  User.associate = function (models) {

    User.belongsToMany(models.Skill, { through: models.UserSkills });

    User.hasMany(models.Team, {
      foreignKey: "creatorId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Membership, {
      foreignKey: "memberId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Rating, {
      foreignKey: "raterId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Rating, {
      foreignKey: "rateeId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.InvitesApplications, {
      foreignKey: "senderId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Message, {
      foreignKey: "userID"
    });

  };

  return User;
};
```

How can I implement my function?

Updated add model Membership in question:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Membership = sequelize.define(
    "Membership",
    {
      interests: DataTypes.STRING,
      contributions: DataTypes.STRING,
      authorization: DataTypes.STRING,
      status: DataTypes.STRING,
      application_letter: DataTypes.STRING,
      date_applied: DataTypes.DATE,
      date_joined: DataTypes.DATE,
      date_departed: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    { tableName: "Memberships", timestamps: true }
  );
  Membership.associate = function(models) {
    Membership.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "memberId"
    });

    Membership.belongsTo(models.Team, {
      foreignKey: "teamId"
    });

    Membership.belongsTo(models.Role, {
      foreignKey: "roleId"
    });

    Membership.hasMany(models.Rating, {
      foreignKey: "membershipId"
    });
  };
  return Membership;
};
```

Updated add model User in question:

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply not equal to in where clause.

```
where: {
    id: {[Op.ne]: teamId},
},
```

Comment: is it at models.Team, if i put it in models.team when I search it didnt give me any user

Comment: if your user table has key teamid, then apply where clause at there as, user.teamid != teamiId. Plus, as you are fetching those users who are not in the team, then you do not require to get team table because those payers are not in the team.

Comment: but if I took out the `model: models.Team...` it will show me user in the team and not in the team. But my user don't have the key teamId. I updated the question added model User for you to look over what I need to do

Comment: May I know how the user and team connect? i mean in which table that relation is defined?

Comment: if it is the `team` table itself with `creatorId`, then show me that model too.

Comment: It's Membership. I will show you the model of user and membership, give me a moment

Comment: Can anyone help me implement this function